# Getting ajaxcart.js to load on the cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax

I have added this bit of code which loads a button onto my cart page which when clicked it opens a pop up window where the customer can select a quantity of the products. The only problems is that the pop up works using the ajaxcart javascript and this isnt being loaded on my cart page.

So my question is how can i get the ajaxcart.js script to load when the cart page is loaded?

If you need more information or i am not being clear please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout .xml file add something similar to:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>ajaxcart.js</script></action>
```

Comment: Just found the answer as you wrote that, i had to add. <action method="addItem" ifconfig="themesettings/ajax/cart"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ajaxcart/ajaxcart.js</name></action> Thank you